# Using SSH In Linux Command

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to connect to my ssh with this command :

> ssh host@myhost ls -l /

but i want to enter my password in the above command , Is this Possible ? for example our command is like this :

> ssh host@myhost mypassword ls -l /

Answer (score 3):

Try to use ssh keys to authentication. See man ssh-keygen. This is more secure way.

Use:

```
"-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ServerAliveInterval=15"
```

to disable interactivity.

Comment: lastly , what is the command ? please help me

Comment: @Jessica Watson, there is not "one" command, learn the tool ssh, read the documentation and tutorials on ssh, its so much more than just "enter this" "receive that", its something you mold to whatever you want once you understand how it works.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-multiple-ssh-key-based-authentication.html

Comment: ummm ... i see , there is no command to connect to ssh directly . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To use SSH without passwords, you'll need to set-up keys to use on your system and the target system.

```
[yoursystem] $ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
f0:7e:55:93:06:b6:c5:6f:68:67:d5:04:7f:2f:ef:df youruser@yoursystem
```

Then transfer the id_rsa.pub file to the target system.

On your target system then add the public key to the list of authorised keys:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Log out.

If you have left the passphrase on your key empty, you can now run the command without having to be prompted for a password (your keys: private key `id_rsa` on yoursystem and the public key `id_rsa.pub` will be responsible for the authentication).

If you have created a passphrase for your private key (recommended), then you'd need to run the `ssh-agent` to keep hold of the passphrases in memory for you:

```
[yoursystem] $ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 1231
[yoursystem] $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Then the ssh-agent will be responsible for providing the passphrase for when you are using the private key (and importantly, the private key is protected by a passphrase and the passphrase is not stored in a file).

Answer (score 0):

No you cant do that, sicne that then the password would be visible by any users on your system, as the command with its arugmetns are visible by a ps aux for example.

If you need host A to ssh to host B without human intervention, then use pubkeys. Put the public key of host A onto host B and vice versa and they can then connect to each other without a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using expect 
expect - programmed dialogue with interactive programs ( utility program ).
but you need to make script for that

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USERNAME@HOSTNAME
expect "*password*"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect eof
```

You need to have expect installed on your system.
Obviously this method leaves security checks ( sometimes necessary, when there is danger of changing host identity.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a bit of software called [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/).  It exposes your password for anyone on your system, but no keys, no expect, and relatively simple to setup.  You should probably get to the point where you have keys, but that's not always possible.